# Force sorting on index (specified specific letter)

Tags: indexing, sorting

I use `indextools` and `texindy`for building my index and it works well but I have a specific entry `von Goethe` and I want to force a specific position of this entry in my index. Currently it is under the letter "V" but it is possible to force this entry to be under the letter "B"?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[texindy]{indextools}
\makeindex
\makeindex[columnseprule,intoc=true,title=Index,name=test]

\begin{document}

Abr\index[test]{AhAg}\newpage
vvhoshf\index[test]{virtual}\newpage
dsvsqd\index[test]{Beta}\newpage
qdqd\index[test]{vonGoethe}\newpage
\printindex[test]
\end{document}
```

If necessary, compilation could be done using `latexmk -xelatex $file` and a specific `latexmkrc` file in the compilation directory containing

```
$pdflatex = "xelatex %S";
$pdf_mode = "1";
$makeindex = "texindy -L french -I xelatex %S";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution using the `\index[]{}` command such as:

```
\index{Goethe@von Goethe}
```